# Is there a way to create and name an object/class, as well as run a method of the class in the same line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am just trying to clean up some code and I was wondering if there is a way to create a new named object as well as run a method in the objects class in the same line. For example:

```
self.equipment_widgets["NumOfStagesLabelCentComp"]=tk.Label(self.parent, text="Number of Stages:", bg="white")
self.equipment_widgets["NumOfStagesLabelCentComp"].place(relx=0.5, y=260, anchor="center")
```

In the first line, I am initializing a new `tk.Label` class as an object in a dictionary called `equipment_widgets`. In the next line, I use the `place()` method to place the label object in my GUI.

If I put `.place` at the end of the first line instead, a `nonetype` object is created.

Comment: Possible yes. A good thing? **No**. For reference you are looking to something of the form: `d.__setitem__(key, tk.Label(...)) or d[key].place(...)` but I **strongly** advise against this. It's ugly and unreadable and doesn't really save that many characters. Just write that in two lines. Or do something like: `label = tk.Label(...); label.place(...); equipment_widgets[key] = label` to avoid spelling the dictionary key twice.

Comment: The latter solution is neat, thanks. I just wish I didnt have to create even more transient names because there are a lot of widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to design your class methods to be chainable, which means that all methods that just modify the object (as opposed to returning information from the object) should end with `return self`. This allows you to write:

```
object.method1(...).method2(...).method3(...)
```

If the `place()` method is designed this way, you should be able to use it on the first line.

```
self.equipment_widgets["NumOfStagesLabelCentComp"]=tk.Label(self.parent, text="Number of Stages:", bg="white").place(relx=0.5, y=260, anchor="center")
```

Note that most mutating methods in Python's standard classes are not chainable, they typically return `None`. So this type of programming is not very pythonic.

Comment: Thanks, I think this kind of answers my question. The `tk` class is imported for me so I dont want to really mess around with the `tk` library code to change the `place()` method.

Comment: I don't agree with your "guesses rationale". I believe the reason is simple: Python encourages you to separate side-effectful methods/functions from other expressions. Not having a return statement (and thus returning `None`) is a way to document a function as performing side effects. Functions or method that do return a value should *try* to avoid side effects. The idea is that mixing side effects into expression often produces unreadable code with a higer chance of bugs.  BTW: To write a long statement you can always wrap it in parenthesis, but yes: short statements are definitely preferred.

Comment: @Bakuriu OK, I've removed my speculation.